# Why is my Nikon D60's light meter causing overexposure in the non-auto modes?

Tags: nikon, metering, manual-mode

I shoot almost always in full manual, not auto-exposure. When I went out shooting, out of the blue, on my first shot, (and I did set the exposure to the correct shutter speed and aperture to match the ISO), the image came out horribly overexposed. I tried it in auto, and it captured the picture perfectly, but in manual, program, aperture priority, and shutter speed priority, the light meter gets it wrong.

I looked in the menus to see if I changed a setting that would make this happen, but there were no settings like that, as it is an old camera and doesn't have all the new modern settings.

I don't want to buy an external light meter, as it would make things more complicated for every photo, and also they cost a lot of money that I don't have the finances to spend, as I am just an amateur.

Comment: What metering mode were you using? Were you metering on dark parts of the scene?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your Nikon D60 has several settings that could result in inaccurate exposure.

- *Exposure Compensation* The D60 allows for up to +/- 5 stops of *EC*.
- *Spot Metering* This metering mode uses only about 2.5% of the center of the frame when metering. If that small part of your camera is pointed to a dark object when you meter it will result in overexposure.
- *3D Color Matrix II Metering* Nikon's Matrix metering has come a long way from the early days when it was almost universally despised by most pros I knew who shot Nikon. But at the time the D60 was created it wasn't anywhere near the level it now is.

**When you are in full *Auto* exposure mode the camera selects *Matrix* metering and disables *Exposure Compensation*.** When you are in PSAM exposure modes the camera uses whatever metering mode and *Exposure Compensation* you have selected. Note that in *Spot* metering mode the camera meters the active focus point unless you have also selected *Closest Subject* for the setting under *AF Area Mode* in which case the camera meters the center of the frame.

It sounds like it may be possible that you have *Spot* metering selected along with *AF Area Mode* including the *Closest Subject* option and are unaware that the camera is not metering at the active AF point but is instead metering the center 2.5% of the frame. You may also have a good bit of positive *Exposure Compensation* selected.

Comment: I currently have matrix metering selected, with closest subject. I will change  the AF-Area mode to dynamic and see what happens. Will check out the exposure comp setting. Thanks, info is very useful

Comment: I checked the exposure compensation and changed from +3.7 to 0. Thanks for the info, I looked for exposure comp in the settings menu, not program. Must have changed it when trying to change aperture, must have accidentally been in program mode, not manual

Answer (score -1):

In Manual, your F and S settings are "set in stone". If there's too much light, the camera can't reduce either, and if the ISO is already at its lowest value... it'll underexpose.

Comment: What are the F and S settings? Did you mean Aperture and Shutter speed? 
Why are they set in stone? If it's in manual mode, isn't that up to the photographer to set them?